# How can I open doc as Read Only from MSWord "Recent Documents" list?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010, read-only

(Office Pro Plus 2010)
I would like to open a non-read-only document from the "Recent Documents" list as "Read Only".  The use case is that the file is on a network share and multiple users are attempting to access the same file at the same time.  The first person to open the file (usually the wrong person) gets it as writable then has to close it so that the group manager can open it and update it.

I know I could browse for it and open as R/O but that adds a lot of clicks to navigate to the folder.

Here's the right-click popup list available in "Recent Documents".  All I need is an option for "Open as R/O".

[image]

Comment: @DavidPostill:  Thanks David for pulling the image into the post.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that the files themselves should not be changed to read only? You just want to open a non R/O files as R/O?

Comment: Correct.  I expanded on post with more info.